# where to add the onclicklistener function in the below code to select the grid view in calendar

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I am trying to write the `onClickListener` function for the particular grid in the calendar so that I can add events to the particular date so please help me where to write the function to select the grid that is the date in the calendar.

```
package com.example.myfitness;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Date> dateArray = new ArrayList();
    private Context mContext;
    private DateManager mDateManager;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    //カスタムセルを拡張したらここでWigetを定義
    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView dateText;
    }

    public CalendarAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        mDateManager = new DateManager();
        dateArray = mDateManager.getDays();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dateArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_cell, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.dateText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        //セルのサイズを指定
        float dp = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()/7 - (int)dp, 
        (parent.getHeight() - (int)dp * mDateManager.getWeeks() ) / mDateManager.getWeeks());
        convertView.setLayoutParams(params);

        //日付のみ表示させる
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d", Locale.US);
        holder.dateText.setText(dateFormat.format(dateArray.get(position)));

        //当月以外のセルをグレーアウト
        if (mDateManager.isCurrentMonth(dateArray.get(position))){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        //日曜日を赤、土曜日を青に color used for weekends
        int colorId;
        switch (mDateManager.getDayOfWeek(dateArray.get(position))){
            case 1:
                colorId = Color.RED;
                break;
            case 7:
                colorId = Color.BLUE;
                break;

            default:
                colorId = Color.BLACK;
                break;
        }
        holder.dateText.setTextColor(colorId);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    //表示月を取得 display the current month
    public String getTitle(){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM", Locale.US);
        return format.format(mDateManager.mCalendar.getTime());
    }

    //翌月表示 display the next month
    public void nextMonth(){
        mDateManager.nextMonth();
        dateArray = mDateManager.getDays();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //前月表示 display the previous month
    public void prevMonth(){
        mDateManager.prevMonth();
        dateArray = mDateManager.getDays();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please, pay attention to the final code in `getView()` method:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Date> dateArray = new ArrayList();
    private Context mContext;
    private DateManager mDateManager;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    //カスタムセルを拡張したらここでWigetを定義
    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView dateText;
    }

    public CalendarAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        mDateManager = new DateManager();
        dateArray = mDateManager.getDays();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dateArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_cell, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.dateText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        //セルのサイズを指定
        float dp = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()/7 - (int)dp,
                (parent.getHeight() - (int)dp * mDateManager.getWeeks() ) / mDateManager.getWeeks());
        convertView.setLayoutParams(params);

        //日付のみ表示させる
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d", Locale.US);
        holder.dateText.setText(dateFormat.format(dateArray.get(position)));

        //当月以外のセルをグレーアウト
        if (mDateManager.isCurrentMonth(dateArray.get(position))){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        //日曜日を赤、土曜日を青に color used for weekends
        int colorId;
        switch (mDateManager.getDayOfWeek(dateArray.get(position))){
            case 1:
                colorId = Color.RED;
                break;
            case 7:
                colorId = Color.BLUE;
                break;

            default:
                colorId = Color.BLACK;
                break;
        }
        holder.dateText.setTextColor(colorId);
        holder.dateText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your events for the particular date here!
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dateArray.get(position);
    }

    //表示月を取得 display the current month
    public String getTitle(){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM", Locale.US);
        return format.format(mDateManager.mCalendar.getTime());
    }

    //翌月表示 display the next month
    public void nextMonth(){
        mDateManager.nextMonth();
        dateArray = mDateManager.getDays();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //前月表示 display the previous month
    public void prevMonth(){
        mDateManager.prevMonth();
        dateArray = mDateManager.getDays();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bogdan i tried it but it is still the same , cannot select the date i mean i want to select any date and add events not just one or two .

Comment: This is an adapter, the onClick affects all dates, not one or two. You add the events to the onClick and this events occur when selecting each day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private List<Date> dateArray = new ArrayList();
        private Context mContext;
        private DateManager mDateManager;
        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    
        //カスタムセルを拡張したらここでWigetを定義
        private static class ViewHolder {
            public TextView dateText;
        }
    
        public CalendarAdapter(Context context){
            mContext = context;
            mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            mDateManager = new DateManager();
            dateArray = mDateManager.getDays();
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return dateArray.size();
        }
    
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_cell, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.dateText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
    
            //セルのサイズを指定
            float dp = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()/7 - (int)dp, 
            (parent.getHeight() - (int)dp * mDateManager.getWeeks() ) / mDateManager.getWeeks());
            convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
    
            //日付のみ表示させる
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d", Locale.US);
            holder.dateText.setText(dateFormat.format(dateArray.get(position)));
    
            //当月以外のセルをグレーアウト
            if (mDateManager.isCurrentMonth(dateArray.get(position))){
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }else {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
    
            //日曜日を赤、土曜日を青に color used for weekends
            int colorId;
            switch (mDateManager.getDayOfWeek(dateArray.get(position))){
                case 1:
                    colorId = Color.RED;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    colorId = Color.BLUE;
                    break;
    
                default:
                    colorId = Color.BLACK;
                    break;
            }
            holder.dateText.setTextColor(colorId);

convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Your code here
            }
        });
    
            return convertView;
        }
    
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    
        //表示月を取得 display the current month
        public String getTitle(){
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM", Locale.US);
            return format.format(mDateManager.mCalendar.getTime());
        }
    
        //翌月表示 display the next month
        public void nextMonth(){
            mDateManager.nextMonth();
            dateArray = mDateManager.getDays();
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    
        //前月表示 display the previous month
        public void prevMonth(){
            mDateManager.prevMonth();
            dateArray = mDateManager.getDays();
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```